# BackButton on Navigation Bar only show indicator without word

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios7, back-button, uinavigationitem

does anyone know how to delete the words above path in the back button? In this case, how could I delete the word "UNIGO!", in iOS7?

I would leave only the direction indicator, without the written

Rory

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the title to be a space character before pushing your friend search view controller.

```
self.title = @" ";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:friendSearchViewControler
                                     animated:YES];
```

And in `-viewWillAppear:` set the title to the actual title!

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"UniGo!", nil);
}
```

Comment: Hello .. So .. I push the link to view the search of the friends I made through the storyboard ... to make these connections normally use the drag to view the animation in push having a navigation bar available.

So in this case where I should set the thiol with the space character, as the push is not done by programming but using storyboards?

Comment: In `-prepareForSegue:sender:`